# Where can I find official POSIX and UNIX documentation?

Tags: documentation, standard, posix

I am looking for official documents on all POSIX standards and specifications. I would like to be able t read the docs to get a better understanding of UNIX systems and how they work at a low level. I've seen links here and there to opengroup.org, which I'm assuming is the entity behind the standards (however, I've heard IEEE mentioned a lot too).

For a good rundown of POSIX, see this question: [What exactly is POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11983/what-exactly-is-posix) It answered a lot of questions for me.

Comment: Sorry but Posix.1 will not give you a better understanding of how Unix systems work at a low level.  The standard only covers a small "portable' subset of the commands and APIs on a Unix platform.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[SUSv2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/)
[SUSv3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)
[POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the web links, you can also install the POSIX man pages, e.g. on a Debian-like system they are available as `manpages-posix-dev` package.

Then you can lookup the POSIX version of say - the read system call - via:

```
$ man 3p read
```

Or the mv command

```
$ man 1p mv
```

Just add a `p` to the usual man page section number.

'to get a better understanding of UNIX' perhaps some books are better suited than the POSIX specification, e.g. 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment' (from a developer centric view) and various 'The Design and Implementation of X', 'Y Internals' or Linux kernel books (from a kernel architecture centric view).