# Compatibility scripting: Save $? for use later

Tags: bash, zsh, tcsh, csh

I would like to write a small part of a script that saves the error status, executes some other code, and sets the error status to the original error status. In Bash it looks like this:

```
<< some command >>; _EXIT=$?;( <<other code here>> ;exit $_EXIT)
```

But I need code that will run no matter if it is being run under bash, zsh, csh or tcsh. I do not know which shell will be used in advance, because it is decided by the user. The user also decides << some command >>.

It is safe to assume that << other code >> will work in all shells, but it is not safe to assume that you can write a file (so putting it into a file will not work).

**Background**

GNU Parallel executes commands given by the user in the shell decided by the user. When the command is finished, GNU Parallel has some cleanup to do. At the same time GNU Parallel needs to remember the exit value of the command given by the user. The code run before the snippet above is the user given command. << other code >> is the cleanup code.

Comment: You forgot `fish` :-) ... The problem is that variable assignment is different for `sh`/`csh`/`fish`, and it's not easy to make this compatible (using `test` or any other commands will never work, since that will reset `$?`)... I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, why don't you just execute your script with `/bin/sh` or whatever? ... The only option is to create separate scrips.

Comment: I'm not crystal clear on what the goal is. As a general construct, you might be better with `_EXIT=$?; <<other code here>>; (exit $_EXIT)`, to allow the "other code" to modify the state of the shell (e.g., `cd`, set variables, etc.)

Comment: @Scott That will not work in csh.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Because the user of this code decides which shell I must use, and I do not know beforehand.

Comment: @OleTange: My point was that, by including the "other code" in the parentheses, you are preventing it from having an effect on the main shell process.

Comment: @Scott Ahh... but that is the goal.

Comment: So, what are you trying to do? This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); perhaps with a description of your goal someone can find a solution (what you want to do there is  nigh-impossible).

Comment: Why does the shell that the user's command runs in affect the shell that you write YOUR script in?

Comment: @Barmar Because it is not a script: It is _part_ of a script where the user decides the shell. So before _EXIT=$? there are commands written by the user in the user's shell.

Comment: You can't generally use the same code in both `sh`-like shells and `csh`-like shells. Their syntaxes for variable assignment and conditionals are totally incompatible.

Comment: @Barmar ... which is the reason this question is here. Given the syntaxes are incompatible, how do you achieve the effect. See a working solution below.

Comment: Why can't you use the user's shell to execute the command they give, but `bash` (or whatever shell you prefer) to execute the wrapper?

Comment: @Barmar Show me how you would do it: Post an answer. It needs to work just as well as the perl answer.

Comment: I don't have an answer. I'm not sure I even understand the context. I don't know GNU Parallel.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use perl:

```
perl -e '$a=shift; `<< other code >>`; exit $a' $? # Fails in csh
```

**Edit** This works in csh, too (and zsh, tcsh, sh, pdksh, ksh93 - though not fish):

```
perl -e '$a=shift; `<< other code >>`; $a=~s/h// and exit $a; exit shift' "$?h" "$status"
```

Comment: Well, if that's a valid answer, why not `sh -c '_EXIT=$?; <<other code here>>; (exit $_EXIT)'`?

Comment: @Scott Just tested your solution in tcsh. It does not work: It seems to always sets $? to 0.

Comment: @Scott With a small change: `sh -c '_EXIT='$?'; <<other code>>; (exit $_EXIT)'` it works and would be a useful answer, too.

Comment: This executes `<< other code >>` under `sh`, not under the ambiant shell. This is not what your question requests, although I expect you'd only care for code that works identically anyway.

Comment: And for that matter this is a syntax error in csh. The csh equivalent of `$?` is `$status`.

Comment: @Gilles It is the **whole** command that must be able to run in all shells, not the `<<other code>>`. I have given background to the question, so hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @Gilles True about csh. So there is still a bug to fix. It works in bash and tcsh, though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works in bash-like shells and csh-like shells, and it doesn’t require perl:

```
sh -c '<< other code >>; [ "$0" != "" ] && exit "$0"; exit "$1"' "$?" "$status"
```

or you can add a dummy/pad parameter:

```
sh -c '<< other code >>; [ "$1" != "" ] && exit "$1"; exit "$2"' foo "$?" "$status"
```

and the test can be changed to `[ ! -z "$0" ]` (or `"$1"`). 
I don’t know whether it will work in zsh or fish. 
Every shell that I’m familiar with will evaluate `$?` and `$status`
when the command is parsed, and pass them to the `sh -c` command as parameters. 
The `sh` shell assigns them to the last two positional parameters. 
When the “other code” finishes, the shell will check the positional parameter
that got its value from `$?` to see whether it is null or non-null,
and exit with the appropriate positional parameter value.

This will fail if the ambient shell uses something other than `$?` or `$status`
to hold the exit status.  It will also fail if the shell allows `$?` to be set
(non-null) if it is not the exit status, or if `$?` is an invalid character sequence
that causes the entire command to be rejected as a syntax error.

Comment: tcsh is happy. csh complains: Illegal variable name.

Comment: You sure about those !bangs? In a classic `csh` the only means of escaping one is with a backslash - not even hard-quotes will do it.