# csh: Get rid of job+PID when forking

Tags: tcsh, csh

With bash I can run:

```
$ ssh bashuser@localhost '( ls -d / nosuchfile ) & echo foo; wait'
foo
ls: cannot access nosuchfile: No such file or directory
/
```

If I try the same with csh I get:

```
$ ssh cshuser@localhost '( ls -d / nosuchfile ) & echo foo; wait'
[1] 187253
foo
ls: cannot access nosuchfile: No such file or directory
/
[1]    Exit 2                 ( ls -d / nosuchfile )
```

I would like to get the same output as bash. How do I avoid the `[1] PID` and `[1] Exit ...`? Can I somehow put `csh` in quiet mode?

The `ls` and `echo foo` are of course only examples. In reality they will be much more complex and will depend on being run under the login shell and I will need stdout and stderr, so a simple `grep -v` of the output will not work.

Comment: I thought this question looked familiar; and you asked a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179364/33645) the other day... What are you trying to achieve here? I suspect you're using the wrong solution to sole a problem you haven't described (ie. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). You should describe the problem you're trying to solve... Making code work in both bourne shell and the C shell is impossible, since they're only superficially the same & very different.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can without some magic trickery (ie. there's no option). You can use `sh -c`, though:

```
$ ssh cshuser@localhost 'sh -c "( ls -d / nosuchfile ) & echo foo; wait"'   
foo
ls: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
/
```

IMHO this is the best option anyway, since there are more shells than `bash` & `csh` (such as `fish`), and you have no guarantee on how any of them behave...

Comment: The point about the guarantee is spot on. This is exactly why I cannot use `sh -c`: There is no guarantee that the command will work in `sh`. Only the user will know which shell is the correct answer; I will not.

Comment: @OleTange What? `sh` is pretty much guaranteed to be on the system. You can't write scripts that behave exactly the same in bourne shell & the C shell, since they're only superficially the same... I don't see how this is not 'guaranteed that the command will work in sh' ...