# Is the "$?" (dollar-question mark) variable available only in the Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, portability

In the `Bash` shell, I can get the command exit status through the `$?` variable:

```
# ps -ef | grep "haha"
root     15439 15345  0 23:02 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto haha
# echo $?
0
```

Is it available only in the Bash shell? Or can I also use it in other shells?

Comment: You can use it in any POSIX shell, it's one of [special parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)

Comment: Related: [Default exit code when process is terminated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `$?` exit-code is common to any shell that follows POSIX, and is described in [2.5.2 Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> **`?`**
>   Expands to the decimal exit status of the most recent pipeline (see [Pipelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)).

Comment: Not only POSIX shell, all Bourne-like shells including the Bourne shell (which I believe was the one introducing it, the Mashey shell had it as `$r` I believe). So that's the sh of virtually all Unix-like systems since Unix V7 in the late 70s, Most other shells (csh, tcsh, fish, rc) have it as `$status`.

Comment: And many scripting languages: Perl, Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 14):

As Thomas Dickey said, any POSIX shell (ie. pretty much all of them) will have `$?`.

This question interested me quite a bit, so I tested it on any shell I could get my hands on:

- `mksh`
- `zsh`
- `/bin/sh` on my Samsung Galaxy S5
- `/bin/sh` on my router
- `tcsh`
- `ksh`
- `dash`
- `/bin/sh` on my virtual UNIX System V from 1989 or so
- `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` on my Windows 10 computer

and `$?` worked in all of these but `fish` and `cmd.exe`.

Found two interesting things:

#### 1. `$?` works in Windows PowerShell!

Well, to a point. Instead of returning 0 or a higher number, it's just `True` and `False`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $?
True
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gfdhgfhfdgfdg
gfdhgfhfdgfdg : The term 'gfdhgfhfdgfdg' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, ...(big long error output).....
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $?
False
```

#### 2. `$?` doesn't work in the shell `fish`.

However, when you type `$?` in fish, you get this message:

```
~$ echo $?
$? is not the exit status. In fish, please use $status.
fish: echo $?
```

I haven't used it much but I'm not surprised, `fish` seems to have its own interesting shell language, completely different from `bash` or whatever.

Comment: Most shells (fish, csh, tcsh, rc, zsh) use `$status` which is a lot more straightforward/legible IMO. Only Bourne-like shells (among Unix shells) use `$?` AFAIK.

Comment: Just depends on how you are reading. I read mentally `$?` as  "sh## happened?" and after that, i never forgot the meaning of this special variable :)