# How do you tell what the return code of a process is when it exits and where is the value usually documented?

Tags: process, fuser

If a process runs and exits it returns a non-zero status (personnaly I prefer the term return code); or even a zero status I know that the value is there (mostly because I've done C++ programming and I know you can at the end of your `main()` method return a value...but also because if I run something like:

`fuser -s ./myfile.txt && echo "a process is accessing your file`"

I know that the `echo` only prints if the status value returned from an `fuser` process is `0`, if it is not, `echo` is skipped all together because:

> "fuser returns a non-zero return-code if none of the specified files
>   is accessed or in case of a fatal error."

Now how do I display this return code to know it's value?  Because if you're running `fuser` with `-silent`, such as in a script, it would seem important to know the value of the return-code/status so I can tell the difference between a file that isn't being accessed and an actual fatal error.

Also, is there a common place in the man pages where return codes / status for a process are documented so I can see what the value might mean?  Or is there a document that has standards for what return codes should be?

Comment: Related: [Default exit code when process is terminated?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99134)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the return code of the last command executed with the special parameter `$?`. There is no documented standard (at least none that are widely adopted) for return codes other than "0" being success and non-zero being a failure. You will have to check the `manpage` of the specific command that you are running.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255976 has more details.

Comment: No documented standard, besides that of http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/sysexits.3 (as for knowing about it or following it, well, that's a different story).

Comment: So there isn't a designated section of the man page for this sort of thing?   And there isn't something I can search for in regards to this?

Comment: @leeand00 it doesn't seem that way. All GNU `coreutils` appear to use `Exit status`, however `rsync` uses `EXIT VALUES`.

Comment: Well as long as I can get the value I guess it doesn't matter as long as the value isn't the same for two different results;  and that's where the documentation would help.

Comment: Some commands (legacy `vi(1)` is notorious) just return a random exit code, regardless of exit/failure. And "random" is really random, I believe it was just what was left in a VAX register by whatever code ran last before exit.