# Pipe Fail (141) when piping output into tee -- why?

Tags: bash, tee

An example should clarify my question.  This behavior makes sense to me:

```
$ echo hi | cat
hi
$ echo hi | tee >(cat)
hi
hi
```

The first case is obvious.  In the 2nd case, we pipe "hi" into tee using command substitution, and one "hi" is printed by the `tee`'d `cat`, while another is printed by `tee`'s pass through pipe.  So far, so good...

But what happens to the first "hi" in this case:

```
$ echo hi | tee >(echo yo)
yo
```

The return code is 141, a pipe fail.  What could be causing this?

I'm running Mac OSX El Capitain, bash in default terminal app

Comment: What system are you running? I am getting the correct output (both "yo" and "hi") on my systems (Arch, Cygwin, CentOS).

Comment: can't reproduce..

Comment: @tchen Mac OSX El Capitain, bash, running in default terminal app.

Comment: @Jonah: What's the return code?

Comment: @heemayl, i verified on another system that the output is "yo hi".  any idea what could be going on in my system to cause this?  Mac uses BSD tee if that matters...

Comment: @cuonglm, the return code is 141, a pipe fail.  any idea what could cause that?

Comment: `echo` does not print its stdin.  it prints its args from the cmd line.  which doesn't explain why the `hi` isn't being printed or why you're getting a pipefail error code.

Comment: on FreeBSD 10.2 with `bash`  4.3.42(0)-release, I get no output (neither `hi`, nor `yo`) except `Missing name for redirect.`. Exit code is `1` rather than `114`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340706/incorrect-results-with-bash-process-substitution-and-tail/34342525#34342525 for a similar question where I dug into this problem on SO

Comment: @Jonah: Can you run `echo hi | strace -fe write tee >(echo yo)` and paste the output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I’ve figured out how to tweak your experience
to turn it into something other people will be able to reproduce:

```
$ (echo hello; sleep 1; echo world) | tee >(cat)
hello
hello                                                       … and, after a brief delay,
world
world

$ echo "$?"
0

$ (echo hello; sleep 1; echo world) | tee >(echo yo)
yo
hello

$ echo "$?"
141
```

As you hopefully understand,
`>(command)` creates a pipe
to a process running *`command`*. 
The standard input of *`command`* is connected to a pathname
that other commands on the command line (in this case, `tee`)
can open and write to.  When *`command`* is `cat`,
the process sits there and reads from stdin until it gets an EOF. 
In this case, `tee` has no problem
writing all the data it reads from its stdin to the pipe.

But, when *`command`* is `echo yo`,
the process writes `yo` to the stdout and immediately exits. 
This causes a problem for `tee`;
when it writes to a pipe with no process at the other end,
it gets a SIGPIPE signal.

Apparently OS X’s version of `tee`
writes to the file(s) on the command line first, and then its stdout. 
So, in your example (`echo hi | tee >(echo yo)`),
`tee` gets the pipe failure on its very first write. 
Whereas, the version of `tee` on Linux and Cygwin
writes to the stdout *first*,
so it manages to write `hi` to the screen before it dies. 
In my enhanced example, `tee` dies when it writes `hello` to the pipe,
so it doesn’t get a chance to read and write `world`.

Comment: I don't think the problem is what you said. Try the command on linux, you will get 141 return code too. Try strace, and you see bash write to the file first. I guess the problem is the lack of /dev/fd, so bash used named pipe for process substitution, some thing went wrong in this case

Answer (score 3):

To visualize what's going on, compare the following two variations:

```
bash -c 'echo hi | tee >(sleep 1; echo yo); echo $?'

bash -c 'wait_and_tee () { sleep 1; tee "$@"; };
         echo hi | wait_and_tee >(echo yo); echo $?'
```

Notice what's happening in the first variation?

```
$ bash -c 'echo hi | tee >(sleep 1; echo yo); echo $?'     
hi
0
$ yo
```

The command in the process substitution `sleep 1; echo yo` is executed in parallel with the commands outside, and bash doesn't wait for it to finish. So the sequence of events is:

- The three commands `echo hi`, `sleep 1; echo yo` and `tee` are started in parallel.
- `echo hi` writes `hi` to its output (the `|` pipe).
- `tee` reads from the pipe and writes to both its standard output and its command line argument, which is another pipe created by `>(…)`. This results in one copy of `hi` printed to the terminal, and one copy in the buffer of the `>(…)` pipe.
- In parallel with the previous bullet point, `echo hi` exits, which closes the write end of the `|` pipe.
- `tee` notices that it has reached he end of its input file. It has written all of its data out, so it exits.
- From bash's perspective, both sides of the pipe have exited, so the command is over. Since `tee` returned 0, the status of the pipeline is 0.
- One second later, `sleep 1` finishes, and `echo yo` is executed.

In the second variation, I force `echo yo` to terminate before `tee`, by forcing it to terminate before `tee` starts. This time, the sequence of events is:

- The three commands `echo hi`, `echo yo` and `sleep 1` are started in parallel.
- `echo hi` writes `hi` to its output (the `|` pipe).
- In parallel with the previous bullet point, `echo yo` prints `yo` and exits.
- One second later, `sleep 1` exits and `tee` starts.
- `tee` reads `hi` from its input, and attempts to write it both to the terminal (its standard output) and the pipe resulting from `>(…)` passed as an argument. Since the process that had this pipe open for reading (`echo yo`) exited a second ago, the attempt to write to the pipe fails with [SIGPIPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGPIPE) (signal 13, which [the shell reports as 128+signal_number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99112/default-exit-code-when-process-is-terminated/99134#99134)).

[As G-Man explains](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274135), whether `hi` is displayed in the second case depends on whether `tee` tries to write to its standard output or its file argument first.

Without the `sleep` calls, the timing could go either way (I get about half/half under Linux, a different kernel might make one timing a lot more likely than the other).

Comment: In my Debian, I always get `yo`, `hi` printed. There's always a SIGPIPE and return code is `141` in both case. I guess the problem came from the lack of `/dev/fd` in OSX.

Comment: @cuonglm On both Debian jessie and Ubuntu 14.04, I get either behavior randomly. I don't understand why you think the lack of `/dev/fd` on OSX matters.

Comment: Because the lack of `/dev/fd` cause `bash` to use named pipe instead. I remember a bug was raised about the issue before bash 4.3 released. And in my above comment, I mean the command `echo hi | tee >(echo yo)` always produce the consistent output in my Debian Jessie.

Comment: @cuonglm I know that without `/dev/fd` bash uses a named pipe instead of an anonymous one. And I know that in some cases it makes an observable difference, because opening and closing a pipe are observable events. But how does this change the possible behaviors *in this case*?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, that why I don't provide my own answer. I also don't have OSX now for tracing. It will be clearer if the OP can provide the `dtruss` output (I requested him in the comment but got no response).