# How to suppress SIGPIPE in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to execute following code:

```
set -euxo pipefail
yes phrase | make installer
```

Where `Makefile` uses `phrase` from stdin to create installer file. However, this commands ends in error code 141, which breaks my CI build.
This example can be simplified to:

```
yes | tee >(echo yo)
```

From what is see here: [Pipe Fail (141) when piping output into tee -- why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274120/pipe-fail-141-when-piping-output-into-tee-why) - this error means that pipe consumer just stopped consuming output - which is perfectly fine in my case.

Is there a way to suppress pipe error, and just get the return code from `make installer`?

Comment: Unset `pipefail`?

Comment: No, return code is still 141.

Comment: Note that `set -e` has [a wide variety of nonportable, contextually-dependent, generally surprising and hard-to-predict behavior](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises); with details differing [across POSIX-compliant shells, and within different versions of the same shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/). Correspondingly, it makes code hard to audit for correctness, and is generally a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A 141 exit code indicates that the process failed with `SIGPIPE`; this happens to `yes` when the pipe closes. To mask this for your CI, you need to mask the error using something like

```
(yes phrase ||:) | make installer
```

This will run `yes phrase`, and if it fails, run `:` which exits with code 0. This is safe enough since `yes` doesn’t have much cause to fail apart from being unable to write.

To debug pipe issues such as these, the best approach is to look at `PIPESTATUS`:

```
yes phrase | make installer || echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

This will show the exit codes for all parts of the pipe on failure. Those which fail with exit code 141 can then be handled appropriately. The generic handling pattern for a specific error code is

```
(command; ec=$?; if [ "$ec" -eq 141 ]; then exit 0; else exit "$ec"; fi)
```

(thanks [Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32191/hauke-laging)); this runs `command`, and exits with code 0 if `command` succeeds or if it exits with code 141. Other exit codes are reflected as-is.

Comment: And for the paranoid: `( yes; ec=$?; if [ "$ec" -eq 141 ]; then exit 0; else exit "$ec"; fi ) | make installer`  ;-)

Comment: `(yes ||:) | tee >(echo yo)` still returns `141`

Comment: @carbolymer yes, it does; but does your `make` exit with code 141? Your `tee` exits with 141 because `echo yo` stops reading; does that really reflect what your build is doing?

Comment: I think so. `make` at some point also stops reading and in the end I have `141`

Comment: If `make` stops reading, that will cause `yes` to fail with a `SIGPIPE`, not `make`. `make` will fail with a `SIGPIPE` if it can’t *write* to a pipe.

Comment: Try `yes | sleep` instead.

Comment: Or `(cmd; exit "$(( $? == 141 ? 0 : $? ))")`

Comment: See also `[ "$(kill -l "$?")" = PIPE ]` to avoid having to hard code that 141.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to suppress pipe error, and just get the return code from `make installer`?

An alternative solution to the other excellent answers already posted, if you don't want to run your whole command pipe in a subshell (e.g. you want to be able to set variables):

```bash
yes phrase | make installer || { ec=$?; [ $ec -eq 141 ] && true || (exit $ec); }

# generic syntax:
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 || { ec=$?; [ $ec -eq 141 ] && true || (exit $ec); }
```

This uses the `exit` command in a subshell to preserve the original exit code from the command pipe intact, if it's not 141. Thus, it will have the intended effect if `set -e` (`set -o errexit`) is in effect along with `set -o pipefail`.

We can use a function for cleaner code, which allows the use of `return` instead of the `exit` in a subshell trick:

```bash
handle_pipefails() { 
    # ignore exit code 141 from simple command pipes
    # - use with: cmd1 | cmd2 || handle_pipefails $?
    (( $1 == 141 )) && return 0
    return $1
}

# then use it or test it as:
yes | head -n 1 || handle_pipefails $?
echo "ec=$?"

# then change the tested code from 141 to e.g. 999 in
# the function, and see that ec was in fact captured as
# 141
```

An alternative, if you wanted to test the exit code of other commands involved in a more complex pipe, could be to test the whole PIPESTATUS:

```bash
handle_pipefails2() {
    # ignore exit code 141 from more complex command pipes
    # - use with: cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 || handle_pipefails2 "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
    for x in "$@"; do
        (( $x == 141 )) || { (( $x > 0 )) && return $x; }
    done
    return 0
}
```

Comment: handle_pipefails() could be even simpler: `handle_pipefails() { (( $1 == 141 )) || return $1; }`

Comment: Nice one, thanks @intelfx.

Answer (score 2):

```
( yes phrase ; exit 0 ) | make installer
```

Comment: does not make a difference, `(yes ; exit 0) | tee >(echo yo)` still returns `141`

Comment: @carbolymer That's not what happens on my system. Make sure the exit code does not come from `make`: `( yes phrase ; exit 0 ) | ( make installer ; echo "make exit code: ${?}")`

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I've found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464786/ignoring-bash-pipefail-for-error-code-141#comment60412687_33026977
Basically, using:

```
set -euxo pipefail
yes phrase | make installer || (ec=$? ; if [ "$ec" -eq 141 ]; then exit 0; else exit "$ec"; fi)
```

just filters out `SIGPIPE` from return codes.

Comment: This will hide the real exit code for any other failure...