# How to get Bash to exit with a given exit code

Tags: bash

Why does the following print 0? I expected it to print 1234.

```
$ bash -c exit 1234
$ echo $?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bash -c exit 1234
```

runs bash with the separate arguments `-c`, `exit`, and `1234`. `-c` consumes the argument immediately following it, so bash runs `exit` only; `1234` is used as the first positional parameter (`$0`, the name of the shell).

To get bash to exit with a given code, you need to quote the whole command:

```
bash -c "exit 1234"
```

Note that bash exit statuses are limited to 0-255, so this produces an exit status of 210 (1234 % 256).

Answer (score 2):

You can't with `bash`'s `exit` builtin even if you fix your code to run `exit 1234` instead of `exit` alone, as `bash` takes upon itself to truncate the value to 8 bits:

```
$ strace -e exit_group bash -c 'exit 1234'
exit_group(210)                         = ?
```

You need to execute another command in the same process that can exit with arbitrary values:

```
$ strace -e exit_group bash -c 'exec perl -e "exit 1234"'
exit_group(1234)                        = ?
```

```
$ strace -e exit_group bash -c 'exec zsh -c "exit 1234"'
exit_group(1234)                        = ?
```

In any case, note that some systems like Linux don't let the parent process access the full value of that exit status even when using the `waitid()` API or a SIGCHLD `sigaction()` handler which is required by POSIX not to truncate it.

More details on that at:

- [What is the min and max values of exit codes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/418784)
- [Default exit code when process is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112)

Comment: Thanks. I used the number 1234 as just a placeholder, as my puzzle was that it was returning 0 (because of the error in my command line as pointed out by the other answer). I should have just used 123 in my question instead of 1234. But your answer is interesting nevertheless.