# What is exit $? in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

In shell-script, what is this command? `exit $?`

I didn't find any resource to explain it.

Comment: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command

Comment: I just now saw the `exit` portion of this question. @shell-script, please let me know if the linked question does not answer yours.

Answer (score 2):

The intention with `exit $?` is generally to exit the shell with the same exit status as the previous command (whose `$?` is the shell's representation). However it has a few issues:

- Quotes were omitted around `$?`, which means it will be subject to split+glob so would not work properly if `$?` contained characters of `$IFS`.
- if `$?` was negative, like `-12`, as possible if the previous command was a function or builtin in some shells, that could be interpreted by `exit` as an unrecognised option and give an error. `exit -- "$?"` could avoid it but `--` is not supported by all shells.

Those two problems above can be avoided if we just use `exit` alone as it just happens that the default behaviour of `exit` when not given any argument is to exit with the last command's exit status.

You'll find that a common idiom to exit a script when the previous command failed (and exit with the same failure exit status of that command) is to do:

```
that-command || exit
```

There are further considerations when the previous command died of a signal or when the return code from the previous command was outside the range 0 to 127, most of which are described at: [Default exit code when process is terminated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112)