# Why does the bash shebang work, but the sh shebang doesn't, for a string substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've been tracking down an issue I've been facing in a buildkite script, and here's what I've got:

Firstly, I enter the shell of a docker image:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash node:12.21.0
```

This docker image doesn't have any text editors, so I create my shell scripts by concating to a file:

```
touch a.sh
chmod +x a.sh
printf '#!/bin/sh\necho ${1:0:1}' >> a.sh

touch b.sh
chmod +x b.sh
printf '#!/bin/bash\necho ${1:0:1}' >> b.sh
```

I now run my scripts:

```
./a.sh hello
>./a.sh: 2: ./a.sh: Bad substitution 
./b.sh hello 
>h
```

Can someone tell me in simple terms what the issue is here?

[This AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-the-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash) says that bash and sh are different shells, and that in many systems sh will symlink to bash.

What's going on specifically on this docker image? How would I know?

Comment: Obviously, in this image, bash != sh. To be certain, `docker exec IMAGE ls -l /bin/bash /bin/sh`. I suppose that the Bourne Shell doesn't know string substitution.

Comment: Why don't you create your own docker image (possibly deriving the node:12.21.0 one).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is only expected to be a POSIX shell, and the POSIX shell [doesn’t know about substrings in parameter expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) “defines a standard operating system interface and environment, including a command interpreter (or “shell”)”, and is the standard largely followed in traditional Unix-style environments. See [What exactly is POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11983/86440) for a more extensive description. In POSIX-inspired environments, `/bin/sh` is supposed to provide a POSIX-style shell, and in a script using `/bin/sh` as its shebang, you can only rely on POSIX features (even though most actual implementations of `/bin/sh` provide more). It’s perfectly OK to rely on a more advanced shell, but the shebang needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Since your script relies on a bash feature, the correct shebang is `#!/bin/bash` (or perhaps `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), regardless of the environment it ends up running in. It may happen to work in some cases with `#!/bin/sh`, but that’s just a happy accident.

Answer (score 8):

Your script relies on a non-POSIX expansion to parameter expansion, so it won't work on most shells.

This can be solved either by forcing the script to be executed by a shell like `bash` or by **writing a POSIX shell script**, which is a good habit in many cases.

Unfortunally, there is no elegant way to get the first char in a parameter like in `zsh` with `$1[1]`. So use can use

- `"$(echo "$1" | cut -c1-1)"` or
- `"$(printf %.1s "$1")"` or
- the weird `"${1%"${1#?}"}"` which removes the string without first character (`${1#?}`) from the string

Comment: expr may also be an option

Comment: That last example is rather enlightening. I never knew you could do this ina POSIX shell without invoking a command. Also, it’s arguably a great example of useful shell script being a pain in the arse to read...