# Can a Linux command have capital letter(s)?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Can a Linux command have capital letter(s)? I know it's supported but i want to be sure if it's a "problem" or considered "not a good thing"?

Comment: The UNIX convention is to use lowercase for command names, but you're free to call them whatever you wish.

Comment: Indeed, UNIX doesn't care what you call your commands. It will cause much pain and suffering, but you can even have commands with spaces in them: `echo -e '#!/bin/sh\necho hello world' > ~/bin/OH\ NOES; chmod +x ~/bin/OH\ NOES; "OH NOES"` produces `hello world` as expected. (Assuming `~/bin` is in your `$PATH`, of course).

Comment: Check out this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/why-is-the-terminal-case-sensitive) and my perhaps too long [tutorial](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60292/13136).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no restriction on command names on Unix. Any file can be a command. And a filename can be any sequence of one or more (up to a limit though) of characters other than ASCII NUL or ASCII `/`. `zsh` even lifts that limitation for functions where you can have any string as the function name.

A few notes though:

- you'll have a hard time creating a command file called `.` or `..` ;-).
- avoid names that are already taken by standard commands or shell builtins or keywords (at least of the most common shells like `bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh` or `ksh`). In that regard upper case characters can help as they are generally not used by standard commands.
- It's better to restrict to ASCII characters. Non ASCII characters are not expressed the same in the various character sets that are out there
- while you're at it, restrict yourself to letters, digits, dash, dot and underscore. Anything else, while legal, may cause one problem or another with this or that tool (for instance, `|`, `=`, `&` and many others would need to be escaped in shells, if you use `:`, your command cannot be used as one's login shell...). You may even want to exclude `.` and `-` which are not allowed in function names in many shells, in case you want to allow users to wrap your command in a shell function.
- Make the first character a letter. Again, not a strict requirement. But underscore is sometimes used for special things (like in `zsh` the functions from the completion systems start with `_`), and all-digit commands can be a problem in things like `cmd>output.log`. Files whose name starts with a dot will be hidden by things like `ls` or shell globbings and many file managers.

Comment: Right. So I guess it boils down to, don't use anything out of the ordinary unless you have a good reason to do so. Even your second point, I don't think using uppercase to cover those shells are that smart - isn't it better to name the command to describe the change? Like, `zsh_with_some_funky_option` (instead of `ZSH`)?

Comment: Is alias a command?  Because if yes, I had very easy time typing `alias .="echo Hello"` .-) (Well, `sudo vim /bin/.` was harder, though...)

Comment: @AloisMahdal That's why I said _command **file**_. zsh also allows `.() echo Hello`. So does pdksh, but the `.` special builtin takes precedence there.

Comment: Oops, my misread...  Interesting point about the pdksh precedences, though...

Answer (score 27):

Yes it can, and there are a few already. Such as `/usr/bin/X` :)

```
dennis@lightning:~$ ls {/usr{/local,},}/{s,}bin | grep '[A-Z]'
MAKEDEV
amuFormat.sh
GET
HEAD
Mail
POST
X
X11
Xephyr
Xnest
Xorg
NetworkManager

dennis@lightning:~$ zcat ~/.cache/apt-file /archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_Contents-i386.gz | tail -n +33 | cut -f1 | grep -P '^(usr/)?s?bin/.*[A-Z]' | wc -l
758
```

So that's 758 in all of Ubuntu 12.04. Full list: https://gist.github.com/5264777

Comment: No `Xdialog`? :o And you should quote `grep`'s parameter to avoid the shell expanding it in the current directory before execution.

Comment: Don't have it installed on this system :)

Comment: I would like to insist on quoting `grep`'s parameter: http://pastebin.com/Gak7x9rN (Yes, I can edit it myself, but I prefer you understand why.)

Comment: @manatwork someone else already edited that, and I reverted that as I didn't find it necessary. In 12 years of using unix/linux systems I've never had to quote things like [A-Z], as files named A (or B..) are quite rare, only /usr/bin/X comes to mind :)

Comment: Well, it may depend on the shell too. I used uppercase in my example for portability, but my `bash` in my home directory actually expends `[A-Z]` to “c d f h j m p q r t”. So case insensitively.

Comment: Case-insensitivity is bad, unless explicitely requested :) Anyway, I caved and quoted the argument, you have a valid point.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker: Most likely, you didn't mean anything bad, but consider not using stuff like "[i]n 12 years of using" ... In effect, that's pulling rank, although, again, I suspect this is not what you meant. Anyway, great answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Not to mention `zsh` or bash's `failglob` option. I personally typically name my temp files (in `~`) `a`, `b`, `c`... and my temp dirs `A`, `B`, `C`...

Answer (score 6):

A few notes on the historical `STTY` command to clarify some inaccuracies in the [other answer and associated comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70479/22565):

Earlier terminals like the [DEC VT05](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT05) or [VT50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT50) and the teleprinters before that only supported upper case characters. What that meant is that no lower case character could ever be input from them or that they wouldn't be able to display any other letter than upper case ones.

Unix being case sensitive and most commands being lower case, you can see there's an issue there. That's why there are special termio/termios modes (and that are still there in modern Unices even though those terminals are long gone) to handle those.

termio/termios are respectively the older and newer interfaces to control the tty driver on Unix. In a termio(s) `ioctl`, you specify input, output, control flags... that specify how the electric signals on a serial line are to be handled into input and output characters and the internal behavior of the driver wrt things like echo, the line editor... Most of those apply to virtual terminals like modern Unix VGA consoles or pseudo terminals.

The command line interface to `termio(s)` is the `stty` command.

To handle the upper-case terminals, there are three `termio(s)` flags involved:

- `IUCLC` (Input Upper Case to Lower Case): incoming characters are converted to lower case when input. That means the `A` sent by the terminal is considered as a `a`. That means that with this on, I can now type `LS` on my VT50, and the shell will read `ls` from `/dev/ttyX`. I can also now run the `stty` command.
- Now, with `IUCLC` alone and terminal `echo`, while I type `LS`, the driver would send `ls` back to the terminal (so I can see what I type) which it can't display, so we also need `OLCUC` (Output Lower Case to Upper Case), that is we need to convert any lower case letter to uppercase before sending to the terminal.
- Now, we can operate Unix from a VT50, but what if we want to input upper case characters now? That's where the `xcase` *local* flag comes in. This allows (in canonical input mode only) sending an upper case `A` by typing `\A`, and on output, an upper case `A` is rendered as `\A`. (that one is not implemented on Linux)

The `stty` command has the corresponding `iuclc`, `olcuc` and `xcase` settings and an alias for all three: `lcase`. The default setting and what you get after `stty sane` is `lcase` off.

So, when you're on a VT50, all you need to do is run:

```
stty lcase
```

to be able to do anything. But hold on, how do you do that when you can only send uppercase letters? That's where you need a `STTY` command as an alias for `stty`, and that's why `stty` supports `LCASE` as an alias for `lcase`.

There is no such `SANE` alias because you don't want to do `stty sane` when your terminal is all-uppercase.

If you run `stty lcase` or `stty olcuc` by mistake on a normal terminal (try it in `xterm` or any modern terminal), that's where you need to enter `stty sane` to get back to normal. But you don't need a `STTY` command for that. If you type `stty sane`, you *will* see `STTY SANE` echoed back, but that's only the displayed text (not the entered command) that will have been translated, it's still the `stty sane` command that will be run.

Those `iuclc`, `olcuc`, `xcase` flags used to be specified by POSIX (and that's probably why it is implemented on Linux even though I seriously doubt anybody ever connected any of those old terminals to a Linux system (other than for fun)), but have been removed in POSIX:2001.

Answer (score 4):

The most famous command is `stty`, which was also available as `STTY`. It was very handy to set the terminal back to normal behaviour with `STTY SANE`.

Comment: I have `/bin/stty` but nothing else. Care to elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: In the good old days, it was possible for your terminal to become so screwed up, that everything was uppercase. So type `a` and the terminal would see `A`. To restore sanity, you would use the `stty sane` command. Except that this now is impossible, therefore having `stty` available as `STTY` was very welcome. I can't even remember the last time I needed this though :)

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker: **WOW!** That is some cool piece of history!

Comment: Guys (ott-- and @DennisKaarsemaker), you have it backward. I've posted [another answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70555/22565) for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora 18 here:

```
amuFormat.sh
chkrootkitX
enum_chmLib
enumdir_chmLib
extract_chmLib
fakeCMY
GET
HEAD
Mail
oLschema2ldif
POST
smoltDeleteProfile
smoltGui
smoltSendProfile
smp_conf_zone_man_pass.#prelink#.coLtYv
Terminal
test_chmLib
Thunar
X
Xephyr
xfig-Xaw3d
Xorg
Xvnc
MAKEDEV
NetworkManager
amuFormat.sh
chkrootkitX
enum_chmLib
enumdir_chmLib
extract_chmLib
fakeCMY
GET
HEAD
Mail
oLschema2ldif
POST
smoltDeleteProfile
smoltGui
smoltSendProfile
smp_conf_zone_man_pass.#prelink#.coLtYv
Terminal
test_chmLib
Thunar
X
Xephyr
xfig-Xaw3d
Xorg
Xvnc
MAKEDEV
NetworkManager
```

For a total of 50 (of which I didn't know most).

Comment: 50, but 25 distinct ones.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian sid, with zsh, and `ls -1 $path | grep '[A-Z]'`, I get

```
GET
HEAD
HtFileType
Mail
POST
Pnews
Rnmail
X
X11
Xephyr
Xorg
ircII
amuFormat.sh
hpljP1005
hpljP1006
hpljP1007
hpljP1008
hpljP1505
```

**Edit:** Note that, in the command above, that's the digit one, not the letter `l`. A one as in one column.

Comment: With `zsh`, run: `type -m '*[A-Z]*'`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: OK, yours displays the search path, and also includes shell functions. But mine is also zsh-specific: lowercase `$path` is not in bash, for once. Well, the more information, the better.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say yours was wrong, just suggested an alternative (though I'd agree it wasn't the best of wordings). Note that `$path` is not zsh specific. It comes from `csh/tcsh` where your command also works.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Aha, that's interesting! No, my command isn't "wrong" but I agree yours is better because it makes sense to include shell functions and aliases. At least for me it does, because when I use my computer, I don't care if it is a binary, a script, a function, an alias, or whatever, as long as I can run it and it does its job. (I guess the `-m` is for "match".)