# Standard naming practice for executables (binary file) and how to tell whether a file has has non-printable characters?

Tags: files, cat, read, hex

So I am often guilty of running `cat` on an executable file that's a binary file and my terminal usually makes some weird noises and isn't happy. Is there some accepted naming convention for giving an an extension to binary/executable encoded file?

I have an executable file (the output of `go build -o /tmp/api.exe .` and I as I just mentioned I just named it .exe but I am wondering if there is way to check a file before I cat it to see if it's utf8 or whateer.

Comment: "if there is way to check a file". Do you mean like [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file)?

Comment: idk, just check a file if it's cattable before i cat it

Comment: That's what I'm asking you. If you read the file man page I have linked does it do what you need it to? Generally speaking it can tell you whether a file is text, executable or binary.

Comment: What do you mean by "_hex encoded_"? Hex isn't (usually) an encoding. Why should running `cat` on a UTF8-encoded file be a problem? Do you mean you want to check to see if a file is non-text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard naming practice for executables is to give them the name of the command they’re supposed to implement: `ls`, `cat`... There is no provision for extensions which end up ignored from the command line.

To check what a file contains before feeding it to `cat`, run `file` on it:

```
$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b6b1291d0cead046ed0fa5734037fa87a579adee, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped, too many notes (256)

$ file /bin/zgrep
/bin/zgrep: a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
```

This tells me that `cat /bin/zgrep` won’t do anything strange to my terminal (it doesn’t even contain escape sequences, which are identified separately by `file`).

I much prefer using `less` in general: it will warn about binary files before showing them, and won’t mess up the terminal in any case. It can also be configured to behave like `cat` for short files (see the `-F` option).

As [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy) points out, you can make `cat` safe to use on binaries by adding the `-v` option, which replaces non-printable characters with visible representations (`^` and `M-` prefixes). (Rob Pike famously considered that this option [is harmful](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/) — not because of its effects on the terminal, but because of its effect on command style.)

Comment: Regarding best practice: Can you tell if uppercase letters are disallowed by any convention?

Comment: @Daniel see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70441/86440).