# Should Unix sub-command names be case sensitive?

Tags: user-interface

Commands like `git`, `hg`, and `apt-get` all have sub-commands (is there a better name?), and they are all case-sensitive:

```
hg log                    # not hg Log
git status                # not git Status
sudo apt-get install nano # not sudo apt-get Install nano
```

Obviously a lot of things in Unix need to be case-sensitive, because [that's kind of how Unix is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60281/15954).

But in this case, there's no potential ambiguity. Those arguments can only be command names and can't be anything else (can they?). `git`'s error message suggests that this is the case:

```
> git Status
git: 'Status' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        status
```

Besides adding just a little more frustration for beginners and conforming to Unix culture, is there any reason to be case-sensitive?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how being explicit with the case is more confusing to the end user. If a tutorial shows you `git status` then it's pretty obvious that you should type that. The lack of specifying things explicitly has more to do with laziness IMO. The mindset of "case doesn't matter" has more to do with growing up in a Windows culture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any reason to be case-sensitive?

It leaves a much bigger [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) available.  For example, a later version of git could implement uppercase variations on command names, or allow the user to define macros/aliases, as with the shell, where you can define your own `MV`, `CP`, etc. without having to redefine `mv`, `cp`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Case sensitive is part of the POSIX way of handling command and argument it has nothing to do with the meaning.

It's a very good thing that Status and status are not the same because the file system which kind of a base in the system is case sensitive (because of POSIX rules). It's usually a good pratice to keep the same behavior in your whole system.

So for example, if your second argument can be either a filename or a keyword could you consider that keyword is acceptable case sensitive or not ? it would be such a mess to have commands that accept case sensitive argument sometime and sometime not.

The last important thing about key sensitivity in my opinion is the fact that if type `ls -L` you might have define this yourself and really wants to type it with a capital `L` and the system should never try to guess and always execute what you type.

Comment: Do any of `git`, `hg`, or `apt-get` accept filenames or keywords for their first argument? Do any commonly used applications behave like that?

Comment: @dafrazzman I'm speaking in a general way, the goal of the system is to be consistent, not having easier thing set for specific part, also see the last edit

Comment: @Kiwy congrats for 2k!

Comment: @Kiwy So Unix apps have an expectation of case-sensitivity. Therefore you're inviting people to make false assumptions if you make your app case-insensitive.

Comment: @dafrazzman well yes you get it. Making a case insensitive program could lead you to certain problem with the whole case sensitivity of the sytem, plus there's some command that uses letter in small and uppercase i.e: `grep`

Comment: @Kiwy The question is about sub-commands specifically, not commands in general or filenames.

Comment: @dafrazzman but all is about consistency, if argument are case ensitive, why should you change this for some argument that have a special meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Look at it from another perspective. The computer has no knowledge of language or letters, what it sees are numbers that are then mapped to characters. While I (the letter `I`) and | (the pipe) may look very similar to you, they are completely different to the computer.

To illustrate, have a look at the table below. You will see that there is no correspondence between the code for an upper case letter and the corresponding lower case one. They are not consecutive, they are represented by completely different codes (table [source](http://www.asciitable.com/)):

[image]

In other words, while `a` and `A` may seem like the same thing to you, they do not to a computer.

Comment: That's also indeed a nice way to explain this.

Comment: There is a clear correspondence: A vs a, B vs. b, etc. each share 7 out of 8 bits. A single bit—2⁵—tells you uppercase or lowercase. The table is even arranged show the clear correspondence....

Comment: @derobert dammit, I _knew_ some hardcore coder would come and spoil my beautiful logic :). Anyway, yes of course there is a "correspondence" that's how case insensitive file systems work, the point I'm making is that the computer does not see characters but numbers, so the correspondence needs to be worked out, it is not quite a simple as you or I knowing that `A` and `a` are the same letter.

Comment: Sure. And historically, maybe this is why Unix was case-sensitive. But now it's just calling a different library function. The performance difference for comparing option strings is irrelevant. The only reason now is tradition.